Calendar events to Excel - error
I would like to make sure that the events (work activities) that I write daily in the Outlook calendar while I work, at the end of the day, around 7 pm, are copied to an Excel file, in particular I am only interested in the subject and not the description, so only the title and the start and end date of that event.
Be patient, I am new to Power automate. Can you help me understand how to set the following parameters?
1.
[![calendar action]enter image description here]1
2.
[![Excel action]enter image description here]2
3.
[![Excel file]enter image description here]3

I think your post formatting has been compromised - looks like you wanted to post 3 pictures, but none is visible. Can you update the post?
